# Upload documents SharePoint : Problem updating metadata

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, file-upload, vba

I have written a code to copy files from a folder to SharePoint using

`FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress`

But when I do it manually it asks me for **Document status** & **Confidentiality**

I'm not sure how to handle this through VBA.